# Any way to initialize a dynamically allocated structure?

Tags: c, struct, initialization, compound-literals

C11 gives us a neat struct initialization syntax:

```
struct some_struct {int some; char value;};
struct some_struct s = {.some = 5, .value = 'a'};
printf("some = %d, value = %c\n", s.some, s.value);
```

http://ideone.com/zZxTc4

However, it doesn’t seem to work when the struct has to be dynamically allocated:

```
struct some_struct {int some; char value;};
struct some_struct *s = malloc(sizeof(struct some_struct));
*s = {.some = 5, .value = 'a'};
printf("some = %d, value = %c\n", s->some, s->value);
```

This code yields:

```
error: expected expression before ‘{’ token
  *s = {.some = 5, .value = 'a'};
       ^
```

http://ideone.com/nBiorw

```
struct some_struct {int some; char value;};
struct some_struct *s = malloc(sizeof(struct some_struct));
*s = struct some_struct {.some = 5, .value = 'a'};
printf("some = %d, value = %c\n", s->some, s->value);
```

And this code yields:

```
error: expected expression before ‘struct’
  *s = struct some_struct {.some = 5, .value = 'a'};
       ^~~~~~
```

http://ideone.com/SpBX1E

Is there any way in C to initialize a dynamically allocated struct that nicely or do I rather have to write something like that:

```
struct some_struct {int some; char value;};
struct some_struct *s = malloc(sizeof(struct some_struct));
s->some = 5;
s->value = 'a';
printf("some = %d, value = %c\n", s->some, s->value);
```

http://ideone.com/1XAiQS

Which is slightly more inconvenient because (a) it means each member of the struct has to occupy its own line since people tend to frown when they see a `;` sign not being the last sign of its line in a source code, and (b) I’m not able to rely on unspecified values being initialized to `0` as happens in normal struct initialization.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your code

```
 *s = {.some = 5, .value = 'a'};
```

is **not** an [initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization), it's an [assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)).

[Brace enclosed initializer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Initialization) can only be used during initialization.

You can use a ***[compound literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Compound_literals)***, though. Something like

```
*s = (struct some_struct){.some = 5, .value = 'a'};
```

will do the job.

Comment: Qualify the "initialiser" `struct` `const`, otherwise you might end up with two copies, depending on how good the compiler optimises. Despite it's name, a _compound literal_ is not a constant.

Comment: Just adding that this is still not an initialization but an assignment.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya right, we're trying to make the assignment work there. :)

Comment: I'm a little confused (partially by the comments). Assume I do this in a function, then return `s` from the function. Will I run into a segfault, because the assigned struct will be destroyed at the end of the function?

Comment: @domsson not really, as long as the allocated memory for `s` remains valid, the values of the members of `s` will also be valid. The values of the compound literal is stored into the members of `s`.